# How to Keep Focus on a Dropdown List?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a multi-select dropdown list. Currently when an input is selected, if the user clicks on the label to make a selection, the dropdown list disappears. If they click on the actual checkbox, the list stays in focus. I'd like to keep focus on the dropdown list until the user is finished making their selections and clicks the Submit button; regardless of where they click inside of the list. I've tried various combinations of click/focus listener functions as well as playing with the Bootstrap `data` attributes, but nothing seems to work.

```js
function ddInputsChanged($inputs, $outputWrapper) {
  var $inputs = $('#ddDistrict input');
  var $outputWrapper = $('#lblDistrict');
  var outputLabel = 'All';
  var firstChecked = true;

  $inputs.each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      var currentLabel = $(this).next('label').text();

      if (firstChecked == true) {
        firstChecked = false;
        outputLabel = currentLabel;
      } else
        outputLabel = outputLabel + ', ' + currentLabel;
    }
  });

  $outputWrapper.text(outputLabel);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="button-group" style="padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px; margin-left: 18px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Districts&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul id="ddDistrict" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="inpDist1" value="1">
        <label for="inpDist1" class="input small" data-value="1">District 1 (Porter)</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="inpDist2" value="2">
        <label for="inpDist2" class="input small" data-value="2">District 2 (Jones Jr.)</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="inpDist3" value="3">
        <label for="inpDist3" class="input small" data-value="3">District 3 (Horne)</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="inpDist4" value="4">
        <label for="inpDist4" class="input small" data-value="4">District 4 (Haddaway)</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="inpDist5" value="5">
        <label for="inpDist5" class="input small" data-value="5">District 5 (Duncan)</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="inpDist6" value="6">
        <label for="inpDist6" class="input small" data-value="6">District 6 (Willner)</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="inpDist7" value="7">
        <label for="inpDist7" class="input small" data-value="7">District 7 (Brady)</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-info center-block" onclick="ddInputsChanged('#ddDistrict input', '#lblDistrict');">Submit</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="lblDistrict"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick in a little test. Added stop propagation and added code to close the menu after submit.

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

 function ddInputsChanged($inputs, $outputWrapper) {
          var $inputs = $('#ddDistrict input');
          var $outputWrapper = $('#lblDistrict');
          var outputLabel = 'All';
          var firstChecked = true;

          $inputs.each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
              var currentLabel = $(this).next('label').text();

              if (firstChecked === true) {
                firstChecked = false;
                outputLabel = currentLabel;
              } else
                outputLabel = outputLabel + ', ' + currentLabel;
            }
          });

          $outputWrapper.text(outputLabel);

   $(".open").removeClass('open');
        }
```

Comment: Brilliant!!  Quick question...where did the class open come from?

Comment: It's what jquery ui adds to it when opened.